# Toilet won't come off the flange

Tags: bathroom, toilet

We need to pull the toilet out. Bolts are out of it, water is disconnected from it. It won't lifting it off, Tried twisting it off, then tried running hot water threw it for an hour and tried to remove it again.

The toilet sits on a 2 piece ceramic base (giving us about 5/8"-3/4" space off the floor), we got it out of the way. (thanks to rotted away screw and the other side is broken). We have a little play room now.

So there is the standard iron flange, what looks like 1/4" black rubber gasket material, then 3/8"-1/2" bright red iron spacer(tried cutting it with a hand saw to learn its not plastic.) and then the toilet.

NO SIGN OF ANY WAX RING or even residue from one!!!

Any ideas on how to remove the toilet? or just take a hammer to it?

Comment: Do you have access to a [Sawzall](http://www.homedepot.com/s/sawzall?NCNI-5)?  Just cut whatever bolts remain and anything else attaching the toilet.  It'll be less than a minute's work.

Comment: A photo would go a long way to clarifying the problem.

Comment: no, the bolts are out of it. But if i try and cut the flange I'm pretty sure I'll crack the toilet.

Comment: If the bolts are out of it, the flange must be "rusted" to the toilet.  Cutting the flange where there is access for the blade probably won't crack the toilet, but use caution.  A reciprocating saw often has variable speed control:  set that to minimize resonances which would crack the toilet.

Comment: I know my way around a sawzall.  but its the space i have to work with that I'm worried about.

Comment: Sorry, I am having trouble visualizing the situation.  Please add a photo or diagram to your question.

Comment: Replacement toilets aren't that expensive and have bolt holes in predictable places.  I'm liking the "just take a hammer to it" approach.

Answer (score 2):

I'm betting that whomever installed it last used an adhesive to secure and seal the toilet to the closet flange and/or the floor. It sounds as if you are renovating so unless the toilet has value (or fond memories) break it out with long handled sledge hammers (use eye protection). The time saved by not solving a mad scientist monstrosity might be worth the cost of a mid-priced new toilet.